# My code just return first product information

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, nonetype

Using Beautifulsoup to scrap all information for all products. but my code just return first product information. Also when I add .text at the end of find element, it return noneType

```
options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("headless")
driver=chrome(executable_path="/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Driver/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.adiglobaldistribution.us/MyAccount/signin")# here change your link
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(5)
wait=WebDriverWait(driver,10)

data_adi = []
n=0
for n in range(12):
     pages_url = f"https://www.adiglobaldistribution.us/search?page={n+1}&criteria=Tp-link%20Usa%20Corporation"
     driver.get(pages_url)
     WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[class="rd-thumb-details-price"]')))
     time.sleep(5)
     html = driver.page_source
     soup = Soup(html)

     for item in soup.select("div", class_='[class="rd-thumb-details-price"]'):
          data_adi.append({
              'title' : item.find("span", class_="rd-item-name"),
              'name' : item.find("span", class_='item-num-mfg'),
              'link' : item.find("div", class_="rd-item-name", href=True),
              'price' : item.find("div", class_="pdp-price-wrapper"),
              'stock' : item.find("span", class_="availabilityMessage-rd")
          })
df_adi = pd.DataFrame(data_adi)
df_adi.drop_duplicates()
df_adi
```

Result

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried completely with Selenium. It worked.

I did not include the last two items (`price` and `stock`) as they may need a login. I am not sure though, but you can mimic the locator as written in here for the rest of them (`name`, `title`, `link`) and then take their text into the dictionary (`table`) and then append it to the list.

```
data_adi = []
for i in range(12):
    driver.get(f"https://www.adiglobaldistribution.us/search?page={i+1}&criteria=tp-link%20usa%20corporation")# here change your link
    time.sleep(5)
    wait=WebDriverWait(driver,10)
    search_items = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[class='rd-thumb-details-price']")
    print(len(search_items))
    for each_item in search_items:
        item_title = each_item.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class='rd-item-name'] span").text
        item_name = each_item.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span[class='item-num-mfg']").text
        item_link = each_item.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class='rd-item-name'] a").get_attribute('href')
        table = {"title": item_title, "name": item_name, "link": item_link}
        data_adi.append(table)

df_adi = pd.DataFrame(data_adi)
df_adi.drop_duplicates()
print(df_adi)
```

Output:

```
                                                 title  ...                                               link
0    TP-Link TL-SG1005P 5-Port Gigabit Desktop Swit...  ...  https://www.adiglobaldistribution.us/Product/F...
1               TP-Link TL-POE10R Gigabit POE Splitter  ...  https://www.adiglobaldistribution.us/Product/F...
2                     TP-Link TL-POE160S PoE+ Injector  ...  https://www.adiglobaldistribution.us/Product/F...
3    TP-Link TL-SG101616-Port Gigabit Desktop/Rackm...  ...  https://www.adiglobaldistribution.us/Product/F...
4              TP-Link RE220 AC750 WiFi Range Extender  ...  https://www.adiglobaldistribution.us/Product/F...
..                                                 ...  ...                                                ...
137  TP-Link TL-WA850RE 300Mbps Universal Wi-Fi Ran...  ...  https://www.adiglobaldistribution.us/Product/F...
138  TP-Link KL430E Kasa Smart Light Strip Extensio...  ...  https://www.adiglobaldistribution.us/Product/F...
139  TP-Link EAP245 V3 AC1750 Wireless Dual Band Gi...  ...  https://www.adiglobaldistribution.us/Product/F...
140  T-Link Archer T2E AC600 Wireless Dual Band PCI...  ...  https://www.adiglobaldistribution.us/Product/F...
141  TP-Link TL-WR940N 450Mbps Wireless N Router wi...  ...  https://www.adiglobaldistribution.us/Product/F...

[142 rows x 3 columns]
```